# PostgreSQL - What are the best practices for the USING table expression?

Tags: postgresql, expression, using

I'm taking a course about PostgreSQL coming from a MySQL background and I stumbled upon the USING table expression. I know it is a shorthand to, well, shorten the ON conditions for JOINs, but I have questions

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html

- Are they actually used?
- I think that having, say, a "customerid" PRIMARY key on some "customers" table just to be able to use USING is way less unconvenient than just having a normal "id" PRIMARY key as I've always done; is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

USING clauses are used quite often. It is rather a design choice for the tables in a database. Sometimes customers.id is used in the primary table and sometimes customers.customer_id.

Usually you'll see customer_id as foreign keys in other tables.

If in your queries you plan to do a lot of simple joins on foreign vs primary keys structuring the tables to be able to use the USING clause might be worth it if it simplifies many queries.

I would say none of the two options could be considered bad practice.